# Manual assertion in Nightwatch.js not related to DOM

Tags: nightwatch.js

So, the only way I know to do assertions in Nightwatch is via `browser.expect` which is tied to the DOM in some way.

Is there a way for me to do a manual assertion such as:
`expect(true).to.be(true)` and have that assertion tie into the nightwatch testrunner?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you can do `browser.assert.ok(condition)`.  It's not listed in the API documentation but it appears in the example at the start of [API / Commands](http://nightwatchjs.org/api/#commands).  It doesn't chain with other assertion functions so must be done in a callback, as shown.

Comment: I'll try that when I get home and see if it will cause a failed assertion in the test run output and report back.